# Multinomial Logistic Regression as a latent variable model

Tags: logistic, extreme-value, order-statistics, multinomial-logit, logistic-distribution

I was reading the wiki entry for multinomial logistic regression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_latent-variable_model
and it states that we can view the multinomial logistic as a latent variable model by introducing the latent variables $Y_{i,k}^*:=\beta_k \cdot X_i + \epsilon_k$ where the $\epsilon_k$'s are i.i.d. standard type-1 extreme value distributed variables. The article says that

"Actually finding the values of the above probabilities is somewhat difficult, and is a problem of computing a particular order statistic (the first, i.e. maximum) of a set of values. However, it can be shown that the resulting expressions are the same as in above formulations, i.e. the two are equivalent."

I was trying to show that the latent variable model interpretation is equivalent to the usual multinomial logistic regression. I know that if $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are i.i.d. continuous random variables with CDF $F$. Then the CDF of the $j$-th order statistic $X_{(j)}$ is
$$\mathbb{P} (X_{(j)}\leq x)=\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{n}{k}F(x)^k(1-F(x))^{n-k}.$$
and in particular $\mathbb{P}(\max(X_1,\cdots,X_n))=F(x)^n$.
But I couldn't show the latent variable model is equivalent to the usual model, please help.